# Two jQuery 'identical' autocomplete textboxes but only one works

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, autocomplete

I have two jQuery autocomplete textboxes on a mvc web page. One that returns a list of questions and another that returns a list of tags.

The questions textbox works perfectly but the tags text box only sends a null string to its controller.

The jQuery javascript is an exact match apart from the Url.Action, the non working one is displayed below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#searchTag').autocomplete('<%= Url.Action("AutoComplete", "Tags") %>', {
            dataType: 'json',
            parse: function(data) {
                var rows = new Array();
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    rows[i] = { data: data[i], value: data[i].Name, result: data[i].Name };
                }
                return rows;
            },
            formatItem: function(row) {
                return row.Name;
            },
            delay: 40,
            autofill: true,
            selectFirst: false,
            highlight: false,
            multiple: true,
            multipleSeparator: ";"
        });
    });
</script>
```

The Tags Controller is called and returns the Json data correctly as I have hard coded a 'b' string parameter to the LookUpTag method to make sure, but the string t parameter for AutoComplete is always null.

```
    public ActionResult AutoComplete(string t)
    {
        IQueryable<Tag> searchResults = tagRepository.LookUpTag("b");

        var data = (from searchResult in searchResults
                    select new { Id = searchResult.ID, Name = searchResult.Name }).ToList();
        return Json(data);
    }
```

Is there any logical reason for this?

Comment: Two things I'd do: 1) use firebug or Fiddler to check that the URL being requested is exactly what I expect. 2) Make sure your MVC route is passing through the parameter properly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only thing I can see is that your parameter in your action is named `t`. If you're using [this autocomplete plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete/autocomplete#url_or_dataoptions), then it looks like the search value will be sent through as a query string parameter named `q` (i.e. it'll request a url such as `.../Tags/AutoComplete?q=b`). The MVC will then try to match that query string parameter to a parameter on your action also called `q`.

So it might be as simple a fix as changing your action signature to:

```
public ActionResult AutoComplete(string q)
```

Comment: Absolutely correct as the questions controller contains         public ActionResult AutoComplete(string q)
        {
            IQueryable<Question> searchResults = questionRepository.LookUpQuestion(q);

            var data = (from searchResult in searchResults
                        select new { Id = searchResult.QuestionID, Name = searchResult.QuestionTitle }).ToList();
            return Json(data);
        }

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#searchTag')
```

Searching for an ID only returns a single element. Try using a classname.

Comment: He's only showing the script for the one that isn't working, so I think its meant to be targeting one thing by id (and presumably there's another identical script targeting another field also by id).

Comment: Ok, not sure how to do this. Changed the code to be: $('.searchForTag').autocomplete('<%= Url.Action("AutoComplete", "Tags") %>',  <input id="searchTag" class="searchForTag" name="searchTag" type="text" value="Search for tag here" />

Comment: On both of your inputs, you only need a classname, not an id. So:
<input class="searchForTag" name="searchTag" type="text" value="Search for tag here" />
<input class="searchForTag" name="searchTag" type="text" value="Search for tag here" /> AND --- $('.searchForTag').autocomplete('<%= Url.Action("AutoComplete", "Tags") %>', {...})

Comment: @Corey - I think you've missed the point of what he's trying to do. He's got two text boxes, both of which need a *different* autocomplete URL. What you're suggesting would result in the same autocomplete results being populated in both text boxes.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It was the t parameter as above.